# Physics behind chinese magic mirror

Tags: optics, reflection

I was reading about this [strange broze mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_magic_mirror) that seems to project what's behind its mirror side. This mirror has 2 faces, one broze polished face that if you watch with naked eye seems to be a normal mirror, and the other thicker bronze face on which some symbols are incised.
If you shed light through the mirror side, the image on the back is projected ahead and you can see it on a wall if you're in a low light enviroment. I read various articles and this effect seems to be related to the particular way of manifacturing this object.
 I got that the back incisions create some sort of hills and valleys on the mirror which are invisible with the naked eye but do appear if you magnify and project them.
I would appreciate any detailed explanation on the details of the working of this instrument and on its manifcaturing process, because even if it's a very old object, seems to have a very complicated and detailed building process.

Comment: it is more of an engineering type question. see http://complex.gmu.edu/www-phys/phys262/soln/magic_mirror_phy_ed_2001.pdf

Comment: Have you read Berry's article (last sentence on the Wikipedia page you linked, citation [4])? It explains the mechanism very well.

Comment: @eranreches Yes! I didn't understand when and how this convex  and concave part are created. Is it beacause of the way we model the back of the mirror, or is it something that is made afterwards? Does it happen beacause bronze can be modelled this way or can you do that with other metals too? If you can answer this questions I will be glad to accept an answer

Comment: Berry models the mirror as a convex mirror with small perturbation $h$. The perturbation is the result of the carving process of the back side of the mirror, which of course shares the same shape as the relief design.